# How to transfer hash power from one pool to another

Tags: bitcoin-core, mining-pools, mining-theory, hash, hashpower

Is it possible to transfer hash power from one pool to another? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to move all your computational power (hash power) suppose you could just disconnect from your current pool and connect to the other one

If you want to divide between different pool I suppose you could just connect to them then use a tactic of process priority to choose how much power you want to devote to each pool depending on its process, for Ubuntu you could have a look at a thread like this one: https://askubuntu.com/questions/656771/process-niceness-vs-priority but it depend on your operating system